# xQuery on data with namespace?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xquery, xml-namespaces

may a rookie ask for help from you experienced guys, please: how to list/test a value, e.g. subtitle or desc, from a XML file containing namespace ("gsx:onoff" in the example).

My xQuery return no results? Whatever newbie like me tries - return is nothing.

Tried millions of variations of the queries like:

```
    declare namespace gs="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    declare namespace gsx="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
```

```
    let $count := count(//gs:entry/onoff)
```

```
    for $x in //gs:entry
    let $onoff := $x/gsx:onoff
```

```
    return <datarow><icon> {data($x//gs:entry/gsx:onoff)} </icon> <hasdata>{ if ($count > 1) then 1 else 0 }</hasdata><whatdata>{ if ($onoff = "yes") then 1 else data($x/gsx:onoff) }</whatdata> </datarow>
```

```
    //gs:entry/gsx:onoff
```

XML source: [link](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12ZuLAwWcuNmWWiS5bP0oThWjs66emSrJpw2LFly8bPg/1/public/values)

[Check parsed XML source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEbMJ.png)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/'
    xmlns:gsx='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended'>
    <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12ZuLAwWcuNmWWiS5bP0oThWjs66emSrJpw2LFly8bPg/1/public/values</id>
    <updated>2020-12-15T17:13:14.537Z</updated>
```

```
<entry>
        <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12ZuLAwWcuNmWWiS5bP0oThWjs66emSrJpw2LFly8bPg/1/public/values/cokwr</id>
        <updated>2020-12-15T17:13:14.537Z</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006' term='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list'/>
        <title type='text'>Row: 2</title>
        <content type='text'>subtitle: Welcome to the, titles: 2020 CXL Experts’ Meeting, footer: Friday, December 18, 09:45–21:00 (CET), Saturday, December 19, 09:00–15:00 (CET), sponsor: blank.png, allsponsors: all-HALF.png, poruka: Welcome to the CXL Experts’ Meeting 2020.    Day 1 starts at 09:40 and ends at 21:00 (CET) and Day 2 starts at 09:00 and ends at 15:00 (CET).    Scheduled breaks (CET) are on Day 1: 13:00–13:45 and 16:45–17:00 and on Day 2, these are 10:20–10:30, 11:50–12:20 and 13:30–13:50.    Learn more about the meeting at www.cxlexpertsmeeting.com and the Light for Sight foundation at www.lightforsight.org.</content>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/12ZuLAwWcuNmWWiS5bP0oThWjs66emSrJpw2LFly8bPg/1/public/values/cokwr'/>
        <gsx:onoff>yes</gsx:onoff>
        <gsx:subtitle>Welcome to the</gsx:subtitle>
        <gsx:titles>2020 CXL Experts’ Meeting</gsx:titles>
        <gsx:desc></gsx:desc>
        <gsx:footer>Friday, December 18, 09:45–21:00 (CET), Saturday, December 19, 09:00–15:00 (CET)</gsx:footer>
        <gsx:sponsor>blank.png</gsx:sponsor>
</entry>
```

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Paste the _relevant_ code as text instead.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how I can achieve same readability as on the image (pasting XML mess the data up, even "code" tags are used). Anyway, may you help regarding the question?

Comment: If you can't include the whole source XML, at least add the bits with the namespace declarations. Particularly the default namespace.

Comment: Voting to close because there's insufficient information to answer the question (we need to see the XML).

Comment: all right, crucial pieces added, hope this helps understand the question better

Comment: The xml in the link you posted doesn't have `<gsx:onoff>yes</gsx:onoff>` in it.

Comment: It has, but it is (mostly) empty at this moment. For example we can use any other sub-node, inside on <entry> node which start with prefix gsx like titles footer desc... the target is to test value/data/text of any of these gsx nodes. How to achieve that?

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Can you add to your question a couple of examples of what the output is supposed to look like with `<gsx:onoff>yes</gsx:onoff>` and `<gsx:onoff></gsx:onoff>`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: using xQuery I goal getting a value of <gsx:onoff> node(s), test it against "yes" or "no" value and depending is that true or false - show its parent <entry> node (or not).

Comment: I think I get it now; but what is `<icon>` supposed to be in either case?

Comment: So, how to construct xQuery? To test onoff value and list its <entry> node? Not sure about <icon>?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this is what you're looking for:

```
declare namespace gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended";
declare namespace gs="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
let $entries := //gs:entry
 
 for $entry in $entries
    let $onoff := $entry/gsx:onoff,
    $count := count($onoff)
return <datarow><icon> {data($entries//gs:entry/gsx:onoff)} </icon> <hasdata>{ if ($count > 1) then 1 else 0 }</hasdata><whatdata>{ if ($onoff = "yes") then 1 else data($entries/gsx:onoff) }</whatdata> </datarow>
```

Edit:

In response to your comment (I took out the `<icon>` node to simplify):

```
let $entries := //gs:entry[.//gsx:onoff[text()="yes"]] 
 for $entry in $entries
    let $onoff := $entry/gsx:onoff[text()="yes"]    
return <datarow><hasdata>1</hasdata><whatdata>{$entry}</whatdata> </datarow>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, this is giant step forward! Appreciated! On this link you will see the result of  your query... how to select and list in a datarow only those <entry> nodes which has YES value set <gsx:onoff>yes</gsx:yesno>? [result of Jack's xQuery](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bXebgx4kzbUEMMZf1nuTMkELAZ50VCZX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Take a look at the edit, and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Jack for helping me on this! Very close, just need to list content of all the sub-nodes of each <entry> node. This is the query and results now: [print-screen of the results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18JvoTB8RwPci2xsKLuaZC8vERgFX_4CH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using, but when I use it in a proper xml database (BaseX, in my case, but you could use Zorba, ExistDB or even MarkLogic), I'm getting the desired output - the full xml of each `<entry>` node that meets the criterion.